# Magento ajax issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to call magento ajax call request but not success.

I have one .phtml custom page and its contains category when i click on any category need to display category products on slider with ajax .

When i click on any category my ajax call is like below.

```
jQuery('#mytest').click(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/groupedajax/ajax/products",
    type: "POST",
    data: "id=30",
    success: function(data) {
   // alert(data);

    jQuery('#results').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

And Then create controller at : Account/Groupedajax/controllers/AjaxController.php

```
 class Account_Groupedajax_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
     public function indexAction() { // landing page
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
     }
 }
```

Then create config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Creare_Groupedajax>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Creare_Groupedajax>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <groupedajax>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Account_Groupedajax</module>
          <frontName>groupedajax</frontName>
        </args>
      </groupedajax>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <groupedajax>
          <file>groupedajax.xml</file>
        </groupedajax>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Then, layout/groupedajax.php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
  <groupedajax_ajax_index>
    <block type="groupedajax/groupedajax" name="root" output="toHtml" template="groupedajax/groupedajax.phtml" />
  </groupedajax_ajax_index>
</layout>
```

In groupedajax.phtml

```
<?php
echo "this is test";
exit;
 ?>
```

Is's not working, Please help.

Comment: in ajax url: "/groupedajax/ajax/index",  instead of url: "/groupedajax/ajax/products", otherwise define product action in controller as well as in frontend layout.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code

Block  type is not define.

You need to define  block type at `config.xml`.

As per as ur code block type is  groupedajax

Define block type in `config.xml`

```
<global>
<blocks>
<groupedajax>
<class>Account_Groupedajax_Block</class>
</groupedajax>
</blocks>
</global>
```

**Add config.xml**

Add block class `Account_Groupedajax` module at `Account/Groupedajax/Block/Groupedajax.php`